# C# If Method Failed (Catch), DoSomething

Tags: c#, if-statement, try-catch

Imagine, that u have a Method:

```
public void SometimesIFail(string text)
{
    bool everythingOk = true;
    try
    {
         //Anything
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
         //Anything
         everythingOk = false
    }


}
```

Now I would like to do something like that:

```
    foreach (String text in texts)
    {
        if(!SometimesIFail(text)) //If SometimesIFail() Failed (walked into Catch) Do the same for the next TEXT from the List: texts
        {
            SometimesIFail(text); // The Next Text - Until iterated through all the texts..
            //FROM HERE ON, I HAVE A RECURSIVE CALL, THAT MEANS THAT THIS CODE, MUSTNT BE EXECUTED 
            //Any Code..
        } 
        else
        {
            //Do Something
        }
    }
```

Whats the best way, to solve the problem?

EDIT:

After the test (Checking if it was ok), I want to do something, when it did not was OK:

```
foreach (String text in texts)
{
     if(!SometimesIFail(text)) 
     {
           //HERE I will do SometimesIFail(text) for the next text (in foreach)

           // And here is a Recursive Call which should be called, after the foreach iterated through all the texts..
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Lets start with changing 'void' to 'bool',
since you're checking 'if(SometimesIFail(text))', SometimesIFail MUST return True\False.

Comment: It's very hard to determine what exactly your problem is or what you're trying to do...

Comment: u mean I should set A local bool Variable, and set its flag true/false, whenever it walked into try or catch?

Comment: You can't get much info from a `void` method that catches everything. Maybe elaborate on what you really need here.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're try t do? Why are you calling SometimesIFail twice successively?

Comment: I edited a little bit, Hope its more clearly, After one text failed into the SometimesIfail Method it should do the same for the next text, without going further in the code, cause I'm doing then a recursive call.

Comment: You haven't posted any recursive code.  SometimesIFail does not call itself.

Comment: I do that in the real code, not here in the example.. , but thats not important

Comment: @eMi - The line where you do `SometimesIFail(text); // The Next Text` is not actually processing the next text, but rather the same one. You probably need to use `continue` in order to skip to the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the exception bubble up as far as possible. So remove the try/catch from the `SometimesIFail` method and catch the error closer to the user. Something like this:

```
try {
    SometimesIFail();
    // Do stuff 
} catch {
    // Tell the user an error has occurred.
}
```

And do consider exceptions for what they are called - they are **exceptions** and shouldn't be used for flow control. If there is a problem with your code that makes it crash sometimes, fix the problem instead.

Comment: thats not exactly what I want, Look at the Edited text

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what you want, because instead of telling the user an error has occurred, you can just do **nothing at all**, and the `foreach` loop will just continue with the next item in the list. But swallowing errors without taking action is a really poor code design, and you should focus on **solving the problem** instead!

Comment: Fixing the Problem isnt Possible, because I'm working with the Webclient class and getting Urls from a Website and sometimes a Url fails (404 Server Error) ;)

Comment: Servers beyond your control may fail, and that is not an unexpected error. If you get a 404, it is the fault of the client for requesting the **wrong url**! If you get a 500, you should catch the WebException, store the error somewhere and preferably **tell the user**. Just continuing along with the next item in the list is problably not the right way to go, but it depends on the type of error you are getting.

Comment: mhm I did what u said, but I wasn't able to solve my problem, after he walked into catch, he executed the further code, thats not the idea.. But anyway I will mark this as responsed, thanks for your commitment anyway.. :D

Comment: If there is code that shouldn't be executed when an exception is thrown, put all of that code in the `try` block. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think without try catch if you solved your problem then it would be better option...

Comment: I dont really understand what u mean? If I remove the Try/Catch, the program will shutdown :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
public bool SometimesIFail(string text) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
         //Anything
         return false;
    } 
    catch(Exception) 
    { 
         //Anything
         return true;
    } 
}

foreach (String text in texts)  
{  
    SometimesIFail(text);  
    if(SometimesIFail(text)) 
    { 
        // returned true - exception was thrown
        SometimesIFail(text);
    }   
    else  
    {  
        //Do Something  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought I knew what you were looking for, then I read the comments in the code snippet, so now I'm not so sure. Here is my answer based on what I think you want. It looks like you want to check the `SometimesIFail` method for success and if it succeeds execute some code, if it fails you want to continue to the next iteration. Here's what I would do for that scenario:

```
// Don't use a void here, use a bool
public bool SometimesIFail(string text)
{
    try
    {
         //Anything
         return true;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
         //Anything
         return false;
    }
}
```

....

```
foreach (String text in texts)
{
    if(SometimesIFail(text)) // Evaluates to true for success
    {
        // Do your success matching code
    }

    // There doesn't need to be an else condition if you're
    // only passing to the next iteration
}
```

Comment: take a look to my edited answer, the first Problem is solved (with true/false in try/catch)

Comment: @eMi: Sorry, in your edited answer, the first problem has not changed except that there is an unused boolean localized within it, and the rest of it is as unclear as ever.

Comment: yes I must do return true or false, but thats not my mainproblem... the other problem is important, but now I marked the answer as responsed, I think its maybe to hard to understand..